# "fatal error : glew no such files or directory found compilation terminated" in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am completely new to programming. While compiling visual studio showed me this in terminal while simply building a hello world program.
fatal error :  glew no such files or directory found compilation terminated"
Please help me with this.

[image]

mn.cpp

```
  #include <iostream>
#include<glew.h>
#include<glut.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    cout<<" fatal error no such file or directory compilation termited";
    return 0;
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json files

```
    "configurations": [
    {

        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/resources/glew/GL/*",
            "/resources/glut/glut/*"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],

        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

Comment: I have no experience with VS code, but are you sure the includepath should contain globs like ** and * instead of just directory entries?

Comment: Ah, [the official documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md) mention that ** is handled specially. Still, your path for `glew` and `glut` should not end in *. In fact, I think it should just be `/resources/glew` and `/resources/glut` and then `#include <GL/glew.h>`